# Update contact activity in Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to trace the path of the customer in a Journey Builder, with the Update contact activity.

But if the customer is in more than one campaign, Will it update contact activity overwrite the record?

How can I know if a customer is on several journeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will overwrite it.

To be able to manage subscribers in journeys directly from Sales Cloud and to have a view of all journeys they are currently in, I would recommend the following app from Salesforce Labs, which you can download for free from AppExchange: [Marketing Cloud Journeys for Salesforce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FZBjRUAX).

**Marketing Cloud Journeys for Salesforce** is a Lightning Component which can be added to the Contact, Lead, Case or Account page and it will display the list of Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journeys that the subscriber is currently in, along with a stop button to allow instant removal of the said subscriber from the Journey.

[image]

Read more: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/06/26/manage-contacts-and-leads-in-marketing-cloud-journeys-directly-from-your-salesforce-org/

Comment: thank u so much zuzannamj. your advice was very helpful. 
but to track the logs within SFMC is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a Data Extension. Depending on which DE you use, you can track all journeys in the same DE or use a dedicated DE for each journey, for example, the journey's own DE. Read this for more details: https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/

Comment: if I want to keep track of all the trips in the same DE, I have to build an attribute group and link this DE to contact, but the relationship must be 1-M? because a subscriber can stay in multiple journeys. right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right

Comment: must necessarily be connected to attribute group?